# Tables in Google Cloud Sql

Tags: sql, cloud, google-cloud-sql

How does one edit tables on Google Cloud SQL using MySQL workbench? I have created a database on MySQL and it is visible on Cloud SQL. However I am unable to view the tables as the database is grayed out on Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Tables won't be shown in the developer console.

If you could connect to the particular database through workbench client, it is fine to create the table(s) inside workbench client itself. It actually shows a mirror of your Cloud SQL database.